# Why does the test text briefly disappear when I click on the checkbox？

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why does the test text briefly disappear when I click on the checkbox？
test in windows 10 ，microsoft edge 88
demo url:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-fire-wftnb?file=/index.js

Comment: I don't see that happening in your demo on my machine.  Perhaps it's a platform specific reason?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer it's happening, when you click on the `checkbox` but not happening on clicking on `label`

Comment: Seriously, I don't see it happening for me.  Chrome on MacBook.

Comment: Works just fine here: Windows + Chrome and Firefox.